How to test an Angular directive method that requires access to an ElementRef of an injected component
I'm working on an Angular application where I have a component that uses a custom directive called ExampleDirective. This directive needs to access a  element within the component and perform some operations with it.
Here's the structure of my code:
@Directive({
    selector: '[exampleDirective]',
})
export class ExampleDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(public component: Component) { }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.doSomething();

        this.component.control.valueChanges
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.doSomething();
            });
    }

    public doSomething(): void {
        const test = this.component.inputControl.nativeElement;
        // Do something with the textarea element...
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: 'component.component.html',
})
export class Component {
    @ViewChild('inputControl', { static: true }) public inputControl: ElementRef;
    // Suppose 'control' is an instance of AbstractControl or FormControl
    @Input() public control: AbstractControl;
}



component.component.html:

<div>
  <textarea
     #inputControl>
  </textarea>
</div>

Directive use:
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <component
        exampleDirective
    >
    </component>
</form>


However, I'm having difficulties writing a test for the doSomething() method in the directive, as it requires access to the ElementRef of the  within the Component. I've already injected the component into the directive, but I'm unsure how I can access the real ElementRef of the  in the context of the test.
Could someone please guide me on how I can write a test for the doSomething() method in the ExampleDirective and ensure that it has access to the real ElementRef of the  within the Component?
I've tried a few ways, but the inputControl is coming up as undefined.
Thank you in advance for your help!
